# codeigniter ActiveRecord where statement issue

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, where-clause

is have this statement and i want to make it by the Active Records way  in codeigniter

```
DELETE FROM TABLE 
(col1 = value AND col2 = value2 ) OR (col1 = value2 AND col2 = value );
```

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter Active Record is impractical for mixing AND's and OR's within a query.

You will likely need to construct some of the query manually, e.g. something along the lines of:

```
$this->db->where("col1 = $value AND col2 = $value2");
$this->db->or_where("col1 = $value2 AND col2 = $value");
```

Alternately, in your example where there are only two specific columns and two values, the following idea should also work:

```
$this->db->where_in('col1', array($value, $value2));
$this->db->where_in('col2', array($value, $value2));
$this->db->where('col1 != col2');
```

Comment: This is your best bet, like the second idea very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$this->db->where('col1', $value1);
$this->db->where('col2', $value2);
$this->db->delete($table);
```

Comment: Then explain what's wrong with it? Did you even try it? According to your question, you have the exact same where clause on each side of your OR.

Comment: Just because your question was incorrect doesnt mean my answer deserves a downvote. No wonder no one wants to help you.

Comment: @yeah, don't downvote because the question is updated and answer is not updated.

Answer (score -2):

That's not the goal of active record. As name suggest active record object instance is tied to a single row in a table. If you want to do this in "active record way" you have to retrieve all the records you have to delete the database, mark them as deleted and commit changes witch is overkill. Best you can do is to get connection instance from codeignither and execute query manually.

Comment: False. You can delete more than one row using active record.

Comment: you can delete more than one record with "current" implementation but active record isn't designed to do that. Still the best solution is not to use active record.

Comment: But active record allows you to select more than 1 row. Do you think that that is not how it's supposed to be?

Comment: This answer is not relevant to CodeIgniter's Active Record Class.  I suggested removing the activerecord tag on this question to avoid confusion.