# Login using email or username in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am having a problem with the following codes. I want the user to login using their username or email. When I use username it works perfect fine but when i use email i can login even if password is wrong.

```
public function can_login(){

    $user_mail = $this->input->post('user_mail');

    $this->db->where('email =', $user_mail);
    $this->db->or_where('username =', $user_mail); 

    $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
    $this->db->where('status =', 'registered');
    $query=$this->db->get('user');

    if($query->num_rows()== 1) {
        return true; 
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: just try to delete the = sign from your active records

Comment: This is exactly what you need, I don't want to put it as an answer since it's been written so well here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7512116/codeigniter-activerecord-where-statement-issue

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
$this->db->where("email = '$user_mail' or username = '$user_mail'"); 
$this->db->where('password', md5($this->input->post('password')));
$this->db->where('status', 'registered');
$query=$this->db->get('user');
```

Comment: Thanks Moes, its exactly the same with my solution too.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [CodeIgniter Query Binding](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/results.html#result-helper-methods) like this:

**Change:**

```
 $this->db->where('email =', $user_mail);
         $this->db->or_where('username =', $user_mail); 

 $this->db->where('password',md5($this->input->post('password')));
 $this->db->where('status =', 'registered');
 $query=$this->db->get('user');
```

**To:**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE (email = ? OR username = ?) AND password = ? AND status = 'registered' LIMIT 1";
$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($user_mail, $user_mail, md5($this->input->post('password')));
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you guys this is my solution and works fine.

```
public function can_login(){
$user_mail = $this->input->post('user_mail');
$password= MD5($this->input->post('password'));
$this->db->select('username,email,password');
$this->db->where("(email = '$user_mail' OR username = '$user_mail') AND password = '$password' AND status = 'registered'");

  $query=$this->db->get('user');`

     if($query->num_rows()== 1)
     {
        return true; 
     }else 
     {
      return false;
     }

    }
```